# how do i make a nested dictionary in python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm trying to make an API that fetches memes from Reddit and I am stuck at creating JSON data with nested dictionaries. I have the following dictionaries and I want to merge them together. How do I go about it?

```
{
  "author": "Mizanur1214",
  "nsfw": false,
  "subreddit": "dankmemes",
  "title": "They do be like that",
  "upvotes": 33302,
  "url": "https://i.imgur.com/xZpJFQU.jpg"
}
```

and the other one as follows

```
{
  "author": "Kristis1",
  "nsfw": false,
  "subreddit": "me_irl",
  "title": "me irl",
  "upvotes": 1941,
  "url": "https://i.redd.it/u2qesppixhh61.jpg"
}
```

I want to make something like the following in python

```
{
{
  "author": "Mizanur1214",
  "nsfw": false,
  "subreddit": "dankmemes",
  "title": "They do be like that",
  "upvotes": 33302,
  "url": "https://i.imgur.com/xZpJFQU.jpg"
},
{
  "author": "Kristis1",
  "nsfw": false,
  "subreddit": "me_irl",
  "title": "me irl",
  "upvotes": 1941,
  "url": "https://i.redd.it/u2qesppixhh61.jpg"
}
}
```

Comment: What you want is neither valid Python nor valid JSON. You can however put dicts inside lists: ``[ {...}, {...}, ...]`` which is probably the closest you can get to what you want.

Comment: So, I have to append it to a list and then make it a valid json right? Thanks :)

Comment: Expected result is not a valid dict or valid json. You may want to use list of dicts - which is not json btw. It will be just a list of many dicts.

Comment: @SreeramTP thanks, but how do I convert it into a json from list of dicts?

Comment: json / dict is basically a key value pair. You should have a key and corresponding value. A list of dict can't be directly converted to that. Maybe you can use the list index as the key or you can have a key and the value is list of dicts

Comment: alright, thanks :) @SreeramTP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others pointed out the result is not a valid json or dict.

You need a key for the `dict` object:

```
a = {
  "author": "Mizanur1214",
  "nsfw": false,
  "subreddit": "dankmemes",
  "title": "They do be like that",
  "upvotes": 33302,
  "url": "https://i.imgur.com/xZpJFQU.jpg"
}

b = {
  "author": "Kristis1",
  "nsfw": false,
  "subreddit": "me_irl",
  "title": "me irl",
  "upvotes": 1941,
  "url": "https://i.redd.it/u2qesppixhh61.jpg"
}

res = {"items": [a, b]}

print(res)
```

Output:

```
{'items': [{'author': 'Mizanur1214', 'nsfw': None, 'subreddit': 'dankmemes', 'title': 'They do be like that', 'upvotes': 33302, 'url': 'https://i.imgur.com/xZpJFQU.jpg'}, {'author': 'Kristis1', 'nsfw': None, 'subreddit': 'me_irl', 'title': 'me irl', 'upvotes': 1941, 'url': 'https://i.redd.it/u2qesppixhh61.jpg'}]}
```